# Is this gouge in the side of the tire a safety issue?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

During a routine tire pressure check, I noticed this gouge in the side of my tire:

I'm wondering if it is a safety issue, but I hesitate to take it to a tire shop because I want an unbiased opinion.  It seems to hold the air just fine and it isn't more than a couple mm deep, but I don't want to have a blowout.

[image: tire crack]

Answer (score 5):

That crack was caused by heat and drying out in the sun. It will run, and your should replace the tire.

Comment: Yep, that's one to be replaced sooner rather than later.  There may not be much rubber left under there, the sidewalls of tires are quite thin compared to the traction surface.

Comment: If the other tires are all the same age check them all.

Answer (score 3):

Its always good to replace a tire that has any damage done to the side wall.